# What does GNU make error 58 mean?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am running a build process and it has failed with this error that I cannot find much about.  The error is Error 58, which fails on an object (.o) file.  what does this mean?

Comment: That won't be an error from GNU `make`; it'll be the exit status from whatever command it was running. You'll need to show your `Makefile` and what command it was running.

Comment: Or just look up in the output and look at the last command that was executed. That's the one that failed and likely printed its own error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows: Runtime error 58 usually displays in most Microsoft Windows operating systems. It occurs when Windows cannot insert data into a saved or renamed file that is identical to a file name that already exists in the specified folder.

EDIT: Try doing a clean and getting rid of your intermediate and end files before doing a build. Does it still happen ?